# Can't get external wifi antenna to work, or find one that works

Tags: wireless, eeepc

I have an external wifi antenna (alfa), which worked with windows but not with ubuntu.
My computer is a small laptop eee pc.  The antenna plugs in usb.
Supposedly I have the driver for it, but I am told it is a pain to install!??  Also, on windows there was a way to turn the internal antenna and blue tooth on and off, but now there isn't!  So anyway, how can I:

1. turn internal antennas off and external on
2. install driver
3. get this antenna to work or
4. find another antenna that will work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ndiswrapper (`sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper`).
2. Add `blacklist ath5k` and `blacklist ath9k` in `/etc/modprob.d/blacklist.conf`.
3. Download the asus eee pc 1000 HA wireless adapter Windows driver here:
   http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireles...
4. Install the downloaded Windows driver net5211.inf, existing inside the package atheros xp32-5.1.1.9.zip, using Ndiswrapper.
5. Reboot.

Comment: The link in step 3 is broken. (It's cut off at the end.) I recommend editing this post to fix that.